# ACF - Tags not showing up in Custom Post Types

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, customization, custom-taxonomy, tags

I have a tags taxonomy and then I've added it to my CPT, however it does not give me the option to add tags to my CPT now. How do I get it to do that?

Comment: there's no code in your question can you edit it to include the code? Also your question mentions ACF in the title but nowhere else, how is ACF related? If you're using ACF to register both your taxonomies and CPTs then you'll need to ask this in an ACF community as questions about 3rd party plugins are offtopic here

Comment: That's a big topic with so many possible factors that to try and answer it I would have to make massive guesses. Please edit your question to show your CPT code and how you added tags to it. Then someone has a chance of at least giving an answer that matches your needs.

Answer (score 0):

To enable tags for your custom post type `CPT` using Advanced Custom Fields `ACF`, you need to ensure that you have properly configured the field group associated with your CPT to include a taxonomy field for `tags`

During registering your custom post type, make sure to include support for the tags taxonomy by setting the taxonomies parameter to `array('post_tag')`

```
register_post_type('your_custom_post_type', array(
    // Other parameters
    'taxonomies' => array('post_tag'),
));
```